# Has the defence of 'speed is relative' ever been used in court?

Tags: speeding

On the road we may often see signs on how fast we can go on that road, but there is an ambiguity in all signs, in what frame is the sign saying? Hence, in a way, all road signs could be argued to be utter non sense unless the frame of reference in which the speed is taken is limited.

Has this defence ever been used in course? Does there exist provisions in any legal system to fix this legal loophole?

Comment: What might it be other than relative to the road under the vehicle?

Comment: You could argue that it could be with a car moving along the road, or maybe, since the earth is actually accelerating through space around the sun, the car can never be at absolute rest @GeorgeWhite

Comment: I think that would be a frivolous argument in court.

Comment: You would probably make the judge laugh. But that's not necessarily a good thing: https://youtu.be/EjADAwPw3Jg?t=46

Comment: You would be arguing that you weren’t going 50 mph in a 35 mph zone, but instead you were going several thousand mph in a 35 mph zone. I don’t think that would help.

Comment: I have no doubt that the defense has been used, and I have no doubt that it has failed every time.

Comment: I do know an engineer who explained he had been making efficient use of the available bandwidth of an empty freeway. It didn’t work either.

Comment: @bdb484 given the large number of speeding ticket cases heard and the inconsistency of traffic court, I would not be at all surprised if it worked at least once.  Not that I would recommend it.  At least one defendant must have been acquitted after giving the judge the middle finger, but it is still a losing proposition.

Comment: It should be pretty clear that the frame of reference is that of the speed limit sign and the asphalt.

Comment: @forest So if I take the speed limit sign and carry it at 5mph you are allowed to drive 5mph faster :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 I suppose if you also move the asphalt with you.

Comment: @Damila Your speed is 40,000 km in 24 hours at the equator, that's almost 25,000 miles in 24 hours or 1,040 mph at the equator. Somewhere in mainland USA it will be slightly less. Unless you count the 150 million km times 2 pi every 365 days around the sun, which is about 66,000 mph.

Answer (score 10):

I do not know whether anyone has ever tried it, but it would not take much for a judge to conclude that the only reasonable interpretation of a speed limit sign is that the speed is to be measured relative to the surface of the road or to any other object that is stationary in that frame of reference.

> Does there exist provisions in any legal system to fix this legal loophole?

Most rules for interpreting legal texts fix "loopholes" of this sort by providing for the consideration only of interpretations that are reasonably likely to have been intended, or that a reasonable person might arrive at.  The interpretation that the speed limit could be measured against any frame of reference (or indeed any one other than that of the Earth's surface) is not reasonable.